# How to invoke NtSetInformationFile (w/ FILE_LINK_INFORMATION) in c#

Tags: c#, winapi, ntfs, winpe

The following is an attempt to reproduce the CreateHardLink functionality as described [here](https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.com/2015/12/between-rock-and-hard-link.html).

The reason I even need to do this is because this is the only way that I know I'll have the necessary permissions (this code is running in .Net, in WinPE and has asserted the necessary privileges for restore). In particular, I'm using the BackupSemantics flag and the SE_RESTORE_NAME privilege. The normal pInvoke mechanism to CreateHardLink has no provisions for a restore program to use BackupSemantics...and there are scads of files my account doesn't have "normal" access to - hence, this mess.

```
 unsafe bool CreateLink( string linkName, string existingFileName )
 {
   var access = 
     NativeMethods.EFileAccess.AccessSystemSecurity |
     NativeMethods.EFileAccess.WriteAttributes |
     NativeMethods.EFileAccess.Synchronize;

   var disp = NativeMethods.ECreationDisposition.OpenExisting;

   var flags = 
     NativeMethods.EFileAttributes.BackupSemantics |
     NativeMethods.EFileAttributes.OpenReparsePoint;

   var share = 
     FileShare.ReadWrite | 
     FileShare.Delete;

   var handle = NativeMethods.CreateFile
   ( 
     existingFileName, 
     access, 
     ( uint ) share, 
     IntPtr.Zero, 
     ( uint ) disp, 
     ( uint ) flags, 
     IntPtr.Zero 
   );

   if ( !handle.IsInvalid )
   {
     var mem = Marshal.AllocHGlobal( 1024 );
     try
     {
       var linkInfo = new NativeMethods.FILE_LINK_INFORMATION( );
       var ioStatus = new NativeMethods.IO_STATUS_BLOCK( );
       linkInfo.replaceIfExisting = false;
       linkInfo.directoryHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
       linkInfo.fileName = linkName;
       linkInfo.fileNameLength = ( uint )
         Encoding
         .Unicode
         .GetByteCount( linkInfo.fileName );

       Marshal.StructureToPtr( linkInfo, mem, true );
       var result = NativeMethods.NtSetInformationFile
       ( 
         handle.DangerousGetHandle( ), 
         ref ioStatus, 
         mem.ToPointer( ), 
         1024,
         NativeMethods.FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS.FileLinkInformation 
       );

       return result == 0;
     }
     finally
     {
       Marshal.FreeHGlobal( mem );
     }
   }
   return false;
 }
```

I keep getting a result from NtSetInformationFile that says I have specified an invalid parameter to a system function. (Result=0xC000000D). I'm unsure about how I've declared the structures - as one of 'em has a file name's length is followed by the "first character" of the name. It's documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540324(v=vs.85).aspx).

Here's how I've declared the structures - and the import. This is just best-guess stuff, as I've not found anyone who's declared this in c# (pinvoke.net and other places) I've messed with a number of permutations...all with the exact same error:

```
[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4 )]
internal struct FILE_LINK_INFORMATION
{
  [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.Bool )]
  public bool replaceIfExisting;
  public IntPtr directoryHandle;
  public uint fileNameLength;
  [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = MAX_PATH )]
  public string fileName;
}

internal struct IO_STATUS_BLOCK
{
  uint status;
  ulong information;
}

[DllImport( "ntdll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode )]
unsafe internal static extern uint NtSetInformationFile
( 
  IntPtr fileHandle, 
  ref IO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock, 
  void* infoBlock, 
  uint length, 
  FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS fileInformation 
);
```

Any light you can shed on the dumb thing I've done would be most appreciated.

**EDIT:**

At the risk of drawing more downvotes, I'll explain the context, without which, might have had some believing I was looking for a hack. It's a selective backup/restore program that lives in the midst of state-management software - mostly kiosks and POS terminals and library computers. Backup and restore operations happen in a pre-boot environment (WinPE).

What ended up working, with respect to using the function was the need to change the structure `FILE_LINK_INFORMATION` and a twist in the file naming. First, the working `FILE_LINK_INFORMATION` needs to go like this:

```
[StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode )]
internal struct FILE_LINK_INFORMATION
{
  [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.U1 )]
  public bool ReplaceIfExists;
  public IntPtr RootDirectory;
  public uint FileNameLength;
  [MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = MAX_PATH )]
  public string FileName;
}
```

As Harry Johnston mentioned, the Pack=4 was wrong - and the marshalling of the bool needed to be a little different. The `MAX_PATH` is 260.

Then, when calling `NtSetInformationFile` in the context of a file that is opened with Read,Write, and Delete access and sharing:

```
unsafe bool CreateLink( DirectoryEntry linkEntry, DirectoryEntry existingEntry, SafeFileHandle existingFileHandle )
{
  var statusBlock = new NativeMethods.IO_STATUS_BLOCK( );
  var linkInfo = new NativeMethods.FILE_LINK_INFORMATION( );
  linkInfo.ReplaceIfExists = true;
  linkInfo.FileName = @"\??\" + storage.VolumeQualifiedName( streamCatalog.FullName( linkEntry ) );
  linkInfo.FileNameLength = ( uint ) linkInfo.FileName.Length * 2;
  var size = Marshal.SizeOf( linkInfo );
  var buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal( size );
  try
  {
    Marshal.StructureToPtr( linkInfo, buffer, false );
    var result = NativeMethods.NtSetInformationFile
    (
      existingFileHandle.DangerousGetHandle( ),
      statusBlock,
      buffer,
      ( uint ) size,
      NativeMethods.FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS.FileLinkInformation
    );
    if ( result != 0 )
    {
      Session.Emit( "{0:x8}: {1}\n{2}", result, linkInfo.FileName, streamCatalog.FullName( existingEntry ) );
    }
    return ( result == 0 );
  }
  finally
  {
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal( buffer );
  }
}
```

Note, in particular, the namespace prefix - didn't work until I added that.

By the way, the `DirectoryEntry` describes a file that was supposed to be on disk as of the last backup.

With respect to not using `CreateHardLink`, as the original article describes, there was a vulnerability illustrated using `NtSetInformationFile` where there caller didn't need any particular permissions to add the link. Bummer! I suspect that when Microsoft closed the hole, they also introduced an issue with `CreateHardLink`. I will revisit this posting when I know more.

Comment: Typically, when an API function (FindFirstFile, for example) doesn't provide an explicit mechanism to request use of backup privilege, this is because it *automatically* uses backup privilege if it is enabled.  Have you tried using CreateHardLink() directly to see whether it does the same thing?

Comment: Absolutely - Should have mentioned it. CreateHardLink is returning Access Denied.

Comment: That is - CreateHardLink is returning access denied on *some files* - which is what lead me down this path in the first place.

Comment: Absolutely every hard link that I can't create is in either `Program Files\WindowsApps` or `Windows\InfusedApps`. So...I'm wondering if I'm barking up the wrong tree. These folders are labeled "Mandatory Label Low Mandatory Level" - can that interfere with a backup program?

Comment: I don't think there are very many folders on a typical system that the Administrators group can't write to.  Perhaps you should create one and see what happens there.  Have you enabled restore privilege as well as backup privilege?  I've never been quite sure whether there was any real difference between them, but in principle you should use restore privilege when writing to the disk.

Comment: If you have a Windows 10 installation, you'll have a folder that's called `Program Files\WindowsApps` and there is no access to that folder by the administrator. Of course, the admin can take ownership and set full control, but that's an undesirable side effect for a backup program. BTW - all my backup and restore stuff works except for these "special" folders. BackupRead, BackupWrite and CreateHardLink all work fine.

Comment: I do assert SeRestoreName, SeSecurityName...and a half-dozen others.

Comment: My point was that `WindowsApps` might not be working because of the integrity level or because it is part of the Store, or it might not be working simply because you don't have permissions.  If you create your own folder and don't give the Administrators group access, you can narrow down on the cause of the problem.

Comment: (One obvious workaround in the context of a restore operation would be to *temporarily* change the permissions as necessary, then put them back the way they were.  Personally I'd rather do that than use preferable to using the kernel API, but it shouldn't be necessary to do either.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I wouldn't recommend using the kernel API except as a last resort, I believe your immediate problem is that you are packing the `FILE_LINK_INFO` structure incorrectly.

You have specified packing of 4 bytes, which according to the documentation will put `directoryHandle` at an offset of 4.  However, you are probably running on a 64-bit system, in which case the correct offset is 8.

I'm not certain how to fix this, but my best guess is that you need to use the default packing rules, i.e., not specify `Pack` at all.  (Note that if you specify a packing of 8 bytes, `FileName` will presumably be put at offset 24 when it should be at offset 20.)

Comment: Yes - I took the packing out. MSDN article on FILE_LINK_INFO says it's a 4-byte pack...and my *second* mistake was taking that at face value. First mistake was thinking the CreateHardLink wasn't working, but it works fine if you a.) specify the correct file names and b.) don't have leaked handles all over the place.

Comment: @Clay: the documentation says it requires a 4-byte *alignment*, i.e., the structure must start on a 4-byte boundary.  The alignment doesn't affect the packing.

Comment: Thanks Harry, I've learned an awful lot about NTFS and interop with your help - I've even gone back and browsed a number of your answers just to get the good stuff :-)